# PDO FETCH_ASSOC under PHP 7.0

Tags: php, pdo

Has anyone a clue why this script is working fine under PHP 5.6 and when I change to PHP 7.0 it is not? The results are retrieved correctly, however, when I do

```
echo $translator->customers_customer_data_field_email;
```

there is no output.

```html
    $sql = "SELECT name, value FROM ".$tab_translator." WHERE lang_id=:lang_id";
try {
 $fetchTextTranslated = $conn->prepare($sql);
 $fetchTextTranslated->bindValue(':lang_id', (int) $translator_lang_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
 $fetchTextTranslated->execute();
 }
catch(PDOException $e) {
if ($config->debug==1) { echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage(); }// Throw error msg in debug mode
if ($config->debug==1) { $fetchTextTranslated->debugDumpParams(); }

while ($textTranslated = $fetchTextTranslated->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
   $translator->$textTranslated['name']=$textTranslated['value'];
}
```

Comment: Is `customers_customer_data_field_email` a method to a class or just variable in an object?

Comment: Once you enable error_reporting, you will get more useful hints as to what part failed.

Comment: Joseph: a variable in an object

Comment: If your translator accepts an array (or is one, can't tell from the code) rather use `PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR` instead of a loop.